# Reset Content-Security-Policy for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, content-security-policy

I have a wordpress site runnning in a subdirectory (ROOT/blog/) of my website:
https://example.com/ <- my site
https://example.com/blog/ <- my wordpress installation

Now I redid my main website and added the following Content-Security-Policy to my root directory's .htaccess:
`Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://www.paypal.com https://t.paypal.com https://www.paypalobjects.com"`

Unfortunately, now my wordpress dashboard is not working properly anymore. If I try to create a new post, for example, I just get a blank page. If I remove the Content-Security-Policy from above, it works again.

How can I add a .htaccess for ROOT/blog/ to "reset" the Content-Security-Policy for wordpress? I don't want to do a "allow everything" CSP, but rather recreate whatever the default would be, so wordpress can set everything else.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, WordPress does not have a default CSP, so to get back to normal for that folder you'd need to add an htaccess and unset it. `Header unset Content-Security-Policy`. You said you didn't want an allow everything, but you'll just have to poke through and see what plugins need what manually. You could also [enable reporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only).

Comment: That did it, cheers! If you post an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Using browser inspector console when loading damaged pages by CSP you can find the blocked scripts/images/etc by CSP and fix the .htaccess files according it.

Answer (score 0):

"Since when issue CSP headers through the .htaccess file, its rules are inherited for all subdirectories, it need to make a own .htaccess for the folder /wp-admin/ and cancel the publication of CSP headers in it.

An example of the file .htaccess, which must be put in the /wp-admin/ folder for Wordpress:"

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset Content-Security-Policy
</IfModule>
```

https://csplite.com/csp31/#CMS_admin